# if greater than or less than and zero

Tags: excel, if-statement

This is stock status across the country.

How to apply the if condition following stock statement.

If there is any stock in column A  than its “Blanks” in Column C

If there is no stock in column A (0) and if there stock in column B  than its “To Order” in Column C

If Column A greater than B and IF Column B greater than A than its “Blanks” in Column C

If Column A and B are equal to 0  than its “ Urgent” in column C

```html
UK USA TEXT
1920 0 Blanks
1920 0 Blanks
0 362 To Order
0 362 To Order
113 0 Blanks
113 0 Blanks
196 672 Blanks
1000 89 Blanks
89 1000 Blanks
0 0 Urgent
0 0 Urgent
```

Comment: wont one argument here blank the other? First you want `"blanks"`if col.A has a value, then you wanna see if A is bigger then B? That dont add up

Comment: Have you tried looking up Excel formulas? like googeling "Excel formula if"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look in to these different part of the code. This is tested on Your values. Used `IF` `AND` `OR`

```
 =IF(AND(A2=0,B2=0),"URGENT",IF(OR(A2>0;B2<A2),"BLANKS",IF(AND(A2=0,B2>0),"TO ORDER",A2>0)))
```

Comment: @PETER NP. if you like it you can click and accept it

Answer (score 0):

the third condition :

> If Column A greater than B and IF Column B greater than A than its “Blanks” in Column C

is useless since you already specified if a > 0 then it's blank.

the if syntax in excel is : `=IF( condition ;IFTRUE ;IFFALSE)`

to answer your question try this `=IF(A2 > 0,"blanks",IF( B2 > 0,"to order","urgent"))`

Answer (score 0):

According to all the Conditions Mentioned above, this is your 100% working and tested solution:

`=IF(A1>0,"Blanks",IF(AND(A1=0,B1>0),"To Order",IF(OR(A1>B1,B1>A1),"Blanks","Urgent")))`

[image]

Comment: @PETER you are mist welcome. It would be appreciated if you kindly upvote :)